# SAS/STAT 12.1: KEYLABEL in PROC TABULATE: need row total and column total lines for "all" to display different labels

Tags: label, sas

I am working in SAS/STAT 12.1 and I have only one issue with my code below, I need to show "Total" for the bottom row (displaying columns sums and percentages), instead of "Both Genders."  And yes, the top right-hand column header (displaying row totals and percentages) still needs to be "Both Genders."

I hope there is a simple way to do this using keylabel, but haven't figured it out so far.

```
proc tabulate data=dmhrind format=8.1;  
format gender $gendfmt. ethnic $ethnic.;
class ethnic gender;
table (ethnic all)*f=4. , (gender all)*(n*f=4. colpctn*f=5.1 rowpctn*f=5.1) ;
title 'Ethnic Distribution by Gender';
label ethnic='Race/Ethnicity';
keylabel N='N' colpctn='%' all='Both Genders' reppctn='%' rowpctn = 'Total';
run;
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance provided.

Comment: FYI, you're not working in SAS 12.1, but in SAS 9.3 TS2M1 or later.  12.1 refers to SAS/STAT.

Comment: I don't think there is a good answer to your issue, unfortunately.  As far as I know (and the doc agrees), you can only have one definition for the 'all' keyword.  Unless you can modify your table such that you use a dummy variable for the ALL perhaps, I don't think it's doable.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this that I can see is to make a dummy column that simulates All.  Using sashelp.class:

```
data class;
set sashelp.class;
allage = 'All Ages';
run;

proc tabulate data=class format=8.1;  
class sex age allage;
table (age allage=' ')*f=4. , (sex all)*(n*f=4. colpctn*f=5.1 rowpctn*f=5.1) ;
title 'age Distribution by sex';
label age='Age';
label allage='All Ages';
keylabel N='N' colpctn='%' all='Both Sexes' reppctn='%' rowpctn = 'Total';
run;
```

It needs to have the text you want as the label as its actual value, and you need to replace `all` in the tabulate with that variable (and add it to the class statement), and add `=' '` to override the extra label subrow.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you need to do the titling within the `table` statement.  The following example is similar to yours, using `sashelp.class` (as in @Joe's example) where `age` is used as your `ethnicity` variable:-

```
**  This option helps improve proc tabulate output on some systems;
options formchar="|----||---|-/\<>*";

**  The key is adding the column titles directly in the table stmt;
proc tabulate data=sashelp.class format=8.1;  
  class sex age;
  table (age all='Total')*f=4. , (sex='' all='Both Sexes')*(n='N'*f=4. colpctn='Col %'*f=5.1 rowpctn='Row %'*f=5.1) ;
run;
```

The output should look like this:-

```
      ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
       |                      |       F        |       M        |   Both Sexes   |
       |                      |----------------|----------------|-----------------
       |                      | N  |Col %|Row %| N  |Col %|Row %| N  |Col %|Row %|
       |----------------------|----|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|------
       |Age                   |    |     |     |    |     |     |    |     |     |
       |-----------------------    |     |     |    |     |     |    |     |     |
       |11                    |   1| 11.1| 50.0|   1| 10.0| 50.0|   2| 10.5|100.0|
       |----------------------|----|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|------
       |12                    |   2| 22.2| 40.0|   3| 30.0| 60.0|   5| 26.3|100.0|
       |----------------------|----|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|------
       |13                    |   2| 22.2| 66.7|   1| 10.0| 33.3|   3| 15.8|100.0|
       |----------------------|----|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|------
       |14                    |   2| 22.2| 50.0|   2| 20.0| 50.0|   4| 21.1|100.0|
       |----------------------|----|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|------
       |15                    |   2| 22.2| 50.0|   2| 20.0| 50.0|   4| 21.1|100.0|
       |----------------------|----|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|------
       |16                    |   .|    .|    .|   1| 10.0|100.0|   1|  5.3|100.0|
       |----------------------|----|-----|-----|----|-----|-----|----|-----|------
       |Total                 |   9|100.0| 47.4|  10|100.0| 52.6|  19|100.0|100.0|
       --------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Comment: Huge thanks to everyone who answered, and so quickly.  I really appreciate the assistance.  Joe and ramble, both your solutions worked (of course) and they were perfect for my needs, and your explanations were very clear.  And Joe, yes, I'm in SAS/STAT 12.1--thank you for clarifying for other program help searchers. I have edited my question to reflect the correct program.